# Showing part of buffer or match temporarily in emacs

Tags: emacs

[1]. I have heard that it is possible to show certain part of the buffer temporarily, but I don't know how to do this.

Can anyone share how to achieve this.

[2]. Also will it be possible to show only that line which matches the regular expression temporarily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use narrow-to-* (where * is region, page or defun).  C-x n n is a convenient shortcut for `narrow-to-region`.  Also, you could want to look at `outline-mode`, if what you want is to show/hide sections of your code selectively.
2. M-x occur is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

To add to what @juanleon said about narrowing:

With vanilla Emacs you get only one narrowing: the buffer is either narrowed to that last narrowing or it is widened completely (showing the whole buffer).

With library [`wide-n.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/wide-n.el) you can have [*multiple narrowings*](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MultipleNarrowings) and move among them (they form a ring).

In particular, if you narrow to some region and then you narrow that further, you can get back to your original, wider narrowing --- the full buffer is not your only alternative.